# Flask-SQLAlchemy Data Model Relationship Problems

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a system where a **Person** is part of one **WorkGroup**, and each **WorkGroup** contains many **Person** s. **Person** also contains a list of previously-matched **Person** s. Below is what I have so far, and I'm able to load test names into it successfully. However, when, in the **findPartner** method, I try to assign a new **WorkGroup** to the **Person workGroup** field like this:

```
self.workGroup = WorkGroup(self, newPartner)
```

I get the error message:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'`

Which baffles me. (I've included a more complete stack trace after the listing). Hoping someone can point out the error (I've only been using SQLAlchemy for about 24 hours so I suspect it's something basic).

```
def sanitize(first, last):
    def san(nm):
        return " ".join([part.strip().capitalize().replace(",", "") 
                         for part in nm.split()])
    return san(first) + " " + san(last)


class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    workGroup = db.relationship("WorkGroup", uselist=False)
    prevPairings_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
    prevPairings = db.relationship('Person')

    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.name = sanitize(first, last)
        self.workGroup = None
        self.prevPairings = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def findPartner(self, amongPeople):
        if self.workGroup:
            return # You already have a group
        candidates = [p for p in amongPeople if p is not self and 
                      p not in self.prevPairings and not p.workGroup]
        assert candidates
        newPartner = candidates[0] # Just choose the first available
        self.prevPairings.append(newPartner)
        newPartner.prevPairings.append(self)
        self.workGroup = WorkGroup(self, newPartner)
        newPartner.workGroup = self.workGroup

    def show(self):
        print "<Person %r %r %r %r>" % (self.id, self.name, self.prevPairings, self.workGroup)


class WorkGroup(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'workgroup'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    members_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
    members = db.relationship('Person')

    def __init__(self, *partners):
        self.members = list(partners)

    def include(self, newMember):
        assert isinstance(newMember, Person)
        self.members.append(newMember)

    def group(self):
        return set(self.members)

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return bool(self.members)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.members)

    def clear(self):
        self.members = []

    def __str__(self): return str(self.members)
    def __repr__(self): return self.__str__()


############################################################

def generateNewPairings():
    all = Person.query.all()
    if max([len(p.prevPairings) for p in all]) > len(all) - 2:
        print "All Pairings Exhausted"
        for p in all:
            p.prevPairings = []
    for p in all:
        p.workGroup = None

    def pairUp(everyone):
        if len(everyone) % 2: # Odd number
            oddOne = random.choice(everyone)
            everyone.remove(oddOne)
            pairUp(everyone) # Recurse with even number
            random.choice(everyone).workGroup.include(oddOne)
            return
        for p in everyone: # Even number
            p.findPartner(everyone)

    pairUp(all)
    for p in all: print p.show()
```

**Here's the complete stack trace:**

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1701, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\Bruce Eckel\Dropbox\AtomicScala\_AtomicScalaSeminarLocalServer\AtomicScalaSeminarSQLAlchemy.py", line 242, in generate_pairs
generateNewPairings()
File "C:\Users\Bruce Eckel\Dropbox\AtomicScala\_AtomicScalaSeminarLocalServer\AtomicScalaSeminarSQLAlchemy.py", line 120, in generateNewPairings
pairUp(all)
File "C:\Users\Bruce Eckel\Dropbox\AtomicScala\_AtomicScalaSeminarLocalServer\AtomicScalaSeminarSQLAlchemy.py", line 114, in pairUp
pairUp(everyone) # Recurse with even number
File "C:\Users\Bruce Eckel\Dropbox\AtomicScala\_AtomicScalaSeminarLocalServer\AtomicScalaSeminarSQLAlchemy.py", line 118, in pairUp
p.findPartner(everyone)
File "C:\Users\Bruce Eckel\Dropbox\AtomicScala\_AtomicScalaSeminarLocalServer\AtomicScalaSeminarSQLAlchemy.py", line 63, in findPartner
self.workGroup = WorkGroup(self, newPartner)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 238, in __set__
instance_dict(instance), value, None)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 736, in set
value = self.fire_replace_event(state, dict_, value, old, initiator)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 756, in fire_replace_event
value = fn(state, value, previous, initiator or self)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\unitofwork.py", line 89, in set_
sess._save_or_update_state(newvalue_state)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 1389, in _save_or_update_state
halt_on=self._contains_state):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\mapper.py", line 1928, in cascade_iterator
parent_dict, visited_states, halt_on))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\properties.py", line 929, in cascade_iterator
get_all_pending(state, dict_)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 693, in get_all_pending
ret = [(instance_state(current), current)]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you use `db.relationship()` in both `Person` and `WorkGroup` classes. Set it in one of them and use `backref` keyword argument to define the relationship on the other side.

The other problem is that you've placed your foreign key in the wrong class. Since you want to have [many-to-one](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#many-to-one) relationship between `Person` and `WorkGroup` (many persons in one workgroup), you need to define `workgroup_id` FK in `Person` class and remove `members_id` (and `members`) from `WorkGroup`.

After these changes I've got `CircularDependencyError` exception, most likely due to `prevPairings_id` FK [pointing to the same row](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/relationships.html#post-update). Adding `post_update=True` to `prevPairings` relationship fixed that.

So here are all the fixes you need to do for your code to work:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    # ...
    workgroup_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('workgroup.id'))
    # No need to set uselist=False, it will be determined automatically by
    # type of relationship (many-to-one in this case).
    workGroup = db.relationship("WorkGroup", backref='members')
    # ...
    prevPairings = db.relationship('Person', post_update=True)
    # ...

class WorkGroup(db.Model):
    # ...
    # Removed members_id and members.
    # ...
```

Comment: I will try that and report back. Regarding uselist=False, I'm not sure I understand the comment -- when I put it in then I seem to only be able to assign to None or an object, whereas if I leave it out than I only seem to be able to assign to [] (and perhaps other sequences like set()?)

Comment: What I meant is that `relationship()` will figure out the type of relationship, e.g. that it's one-to-many, and on the side which represents 'one', it will set `uselist=False` automatically.

Comment: Alas, that produced exactly the same stack trace as before. No joy yet.

Comment: Would it make sense to package up the entire working app and get it to you somehow (does stackoverflow have a way to post things?). I'm planning to turn it into an article so I don't need to hide the code.

Comment: Well, you could place it in https://gist.github.com/ or in a similar site. I don't think that StackOverflow has this kind of functionality.

Comment: It's a zip file -- I *think* this should work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wlbcsj9bst4te74/AtomicScalaSeminarLocalServer.zip

Comment: Forgot to mention -- the file to run is AtomicScalaSeminarSQLAlchemy.py and it contains instructions on how to discover the bug.

Comment: Thank you VERY MUCH. I found these issues a bit tricky and intimidating for what seems to me like a relatively simple relationship. Maybe I'll understand these eventually but it didn't seem like it was obvious to anyone, even those who've had some experience with this. Anyway, thanks for your time.